# How to recover after iOS update?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, software-update

Being silly I have agreed to update my iPhone 5c to latest iOS and now my phone looks dead.

When boots, it displays the following screen

[image]

If I connect it to my notebook, iTunes proposes to update phone and starts long term operation, which fails with error 1671.

Next time operation takes longer, now it is 60 mins.

What is it doing for 60 mins? Calculating the mass of proton with QCD? How to avoid this calculation?

How to recover my phone?

If I agree to reset my phone, will I loose all my photos?

Comment: Most of the 1600 series of errors are related to USB connection, installed security software, network connectivity and in extreme cases hardware issues.  [This article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204770) may shed some light.  Other than that, if your phone shows the screen you posted every time you restart the device, you will have to restore it using iTunes and this means that all content on the device will be lost.  As posted by the answer below, good habit is to back up first, then update your device.  Less headache that way.

Answer (score 2):

When iTunes offers to update, tell it to download only.
If that is successful, at least you have the download on your machine, instead of trying to re-fetch it every time there's a fail.

If you have to reset the phone in order to restore, then you will lose any data since your last backup.

If regular Recovery Mode doesn't work, then try DFU (Device Firmware Update) mode.
'Connect to iTunes' is Recovery, black screen is DFU.

To force the phone into DFU mode for restoration

- Plug into iTunes
- Turn the phone off
- Hold power & home for 10 seconds
- release power but continue to hold home
- wait for the computer to recognise the device
  *if the screen lights up while you're doing this, you didn't get to DFU mode & will have to try again; reports say the 10 seconds needs to be fairly accurate*

iTunes should recognise it has a device in DFU Mode & restore should now work.

BTW - Golden rule for OS updates is…
 in iTunes

- Sync
- Backup
- if you really want to be thorough
  Download all app updates
  Sync again
  Backup again
- Download update file
- Update

That way if anything goes wrong you can be back where you were in minutes.